# how to simplify : $\beta =\sin { \left( 2\arctan { \frac { y }{ x } -\frac { \pi }{ 2 } } \right) } $?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to understand how to simplify this equation:

> $$\beta =\sin { \left( 2\arctan { \frac { y }{ x } -\frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }  \right)  } $$

I know the result is $β = (y²-x²)∕(y²+x²)$ but how can I simplify this step by step?

Comment: 1) Use $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ formula to expand the sum inside the sine. 2) Use [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/49a096f6b0f0b866d9286e274ce5404e52aeb902) formula with $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Some useful steps.
$$
\begin{align}
&\sin\left(a-\frac \pi2\right)=-\sin\left(\frac \pi2-a\right)=-\cos a
\\\\
&\cos 2a=\frac{1-\tan^2 a}{1+\tan^2 a}
\end{align}
$$ Then just apply it with $\displaystyle a=\arctan \frac yx$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry to ask but is there more details about how to apply arctany/x to it?

Comment: @ToddLiang Sure. Then you have $$\beta =\sin  \left( 2\arctan  \frac yx -\frac {\pi }{ 2 }   \right) =-\cos\left( 2\arctan  \frac { y }{ x } \right)=-\frac{1-\tan^2 (\arctan  y/x)}{1+\tan^2(\arctan  y/x)} =-\frac{1-y^2/x^2}{1+y^2/x^2}$$ that is  $\beta= -\frac{1-y^2/x^2}{1+y^2/x^2} =\frac{y^2-x^2}{y^2+x^2}$ as announced. We have used that $\tan(\arctan  y/x)=y/x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use $\sin(x-\dfrac{\pi}{2})=-\cos x$ and then $$\cos2\alpha=\frac{1-\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}$$